# Download file from click on image or file link using javascript but it's not work on image

Tags: javascript, jquery

i used this method to download file without show file path in browser tab it's working on docx and pdf file but when i click on image link then it's show the actual path of image which one i don't want so can you help me out this please?

function downloadfile12(file)
{

```
 var baseurl = jQuery("#baseurl").val();
var valFileDownloadPath = baseurl + 'assets/uploads/files/'+file;
```

window.open(valFileDownloadPath , 'Download');
}

Comment: Are you redirecting the path or getting the content and then trowing it back to the browser?

Comment: I want to when I click on file link then it downloads the particular file.

Comment: Look, you are not presenting full code. So what code have you written behind the  `baseurl + 'assets/uploads/files/'+file;` that I'm asking.You might be redirecting the call to another controller action or are you going to get the file content and then returning the content of the file in the same action?

Comment: window.open is a pop-up command, and most browsers block this command. If you want to load data use ajax methods lihe es6 Fetch, or jQuery Load

Comment: https://localhost/projectname/assets/uploads/files/simple.png
this is fulll link.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download an image file in a new tab,you need to add a header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"` on server side to tell your browser to download the image rather than render it in new tab.
If you just want to download the image file,try `<a href="yourUrl" download="imageFile">download</a>`

Comment: I have multiple files not only image and I don't want to user show the file path in the browser when they download any file.

Comment: Browser won't render a file with unsupported mime-type,that's why you can download docx and pdf files even though there is no `Content-Disposition` header